# how to make an image download after finishing a form but the form is done using a plugin on wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I'm developing a website and i have a download link that redirects to another page of a form generated by a plugin in word press, i want the download begin after the user presses submit how can I do that using html or java script??
 this is my download link i only want to do it for the A4 size for now so i either want to know how to make the image download when pressing submit on the form or how i can delay the download of the picture by a few minutes until the user has finished the form

```
<div class="dropdown">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-end">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary dropbtn pull- 
          right">Download</button>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">A0</a>
        <a href="#">A1</a>
        <a href="#">A2</a>
        <a href="#">A3</a>
        <a download href="#">A4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you please try to describe more clearly what you are trying to do, what the result should look like, what you tried so far or where you are stuck,  and add the code of your form? Thank you.

Comment: Is the plugin you are using Contact Form 7?

Comment: @ConnorSmyth no its ERForms will Form 7 help me with what im hoping to achieve

Comment: If you use Contact Form 7 you can hook into the submit functionality quite easily. This ticket may be helpful in figuring out how to hook into the functionality [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926252/how-to-hook-into-contact-form-7-before-send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926252/how-to-hook-into-contact-form-7-before-send)

Comment: is there a way to make a dynamic download using javascript depending on the url that the user is on??