# Contact Form 7 update success message

Tags: wordpress, customization, contact-form-7

I am trying to customise the success message of the Contact Form 7 plugin in WordPress.

I understand that it could be done using javascript, but I don't have this option. That's because I've created a custom coupon code on form submission, by using this -  `add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'dbo_generate_coupon');`.

I need to display that coupon to the user after the form is sent.

I don't want to use an alert. I need to alter the standard "Thank you for your message. It has been sent." response.

I am confident I can retrieve the cookie ok, but the first ( simple? ) step is getting control of the success message. Here I'm out of my depth.

I've tried code like

```
return apply_filters('wpcf7_messages','dbo_update_form_messages',10,1);
```

and

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'action_wpcf7_mail_sent', 10, 1);
```

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'action_wpcf7_mail_sent', 10, 1);
```

Clearly I need help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With a little more digging, I found the answer [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926252/how-to-hook-into-contact-form-7-before-send#29927336)

I updated the code from lukeseager under the heading Send the email to a dynamic recipient

This is my working startpoint;

```
function wpcf7_before_send_mail_function( $contact_form, $abort, $submission ) {

    $dynamic_email = ''; // get your email address...

    $properties = $contact_form->get_properties();
    $properties['messages']['mail_sent_ok'] = 'custom message';
    $contact_form->set_properties($properties);

    return $contact_form;
    
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_before_send_mail_function', 10, 3 );
```